# Composer not loading my psr-0 classes

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-0

For some reason composer can't find my classes. I have a folder structure which looks like this:

```
root
├── src
│   └── Vendor
│       ├── Lib
│       │   └── Class.php
│       └── OtherLib
│           └── OtherClass.php
├── composer.json
└── index.php
```

My composer.json autoload part looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Vendor": "src/"
    }
},
```

And as an example, my `Class.php` file looks like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Lib;

class Class
{

}
```

Then why I try to load that class, from `src/Vendor/Lib/Class.php` I simply do this in my code:

```
include('vendor/autoload.php');

use Vendor\Lib\Class;
$c = new Class();
```

But then PHP gives me the error that it can't find the class.

I already tried to do an `composer update` but that didn't solve it.

So why can't it find my class? What am I doing wrong here?